# For each $i, $i++ display result

Tags: php, foreach, count, auto-increment

I have a function that counts the number of variables equal to one other, I used the technique in php for each, with `$i = 1` and whenever they find `$i++`.
My problem is that I would display the results, but now, if I have four results, it displays `1 2 3 4`.
How do you display only the total result?

PHP code :

```
if(!empty($myvar)) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($identity as $ent) { 
        if(($ent->name) === ($myvar->name)) {
            echo $i;
            $i++; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `echo` outside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(!empty($myvar)) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($identity as $ent) { 
        if(($ent->name) === ($myvar->name)) {
             $i++; 
        } 
    }
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: No worries.. it gets easier ;).  Please mark as solved IF you're happy with the solution.